# Firefox password manager - multiple logins for HTTP authentication

Tags: firefox, http, authentication, passwords

When you're prompted to login to a site using HTTP authentication (the kind with the pop-up box requesting username/password), Firefox's password manager populates it with only the first stored password for that domain.

Is there a way to have Firefox prompt for WHICH account should be used?

It is unlike the normal HTML login forms in which you can just press the down arrow to select from multiple login accounts.

Comment: You might wish to visit [this ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436275) and try to convince JD to fix this - the change to the code is really simple, I've put appropriate patches there (which can be easily ported to new versions - if you're interested I can attach updated ones). You don't need to recompile Firefox, as they alter only XULrunner JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it with [last pass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lastpass-password-manager/) password manager Firefox extension.

Comment: I don't like the idea of an online password manager, even if this is the only solution available. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

One way around this behavior is to create bookmarks for the protected URL which incorporates your username and password:

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.example.com/secretfolder
```

For example, if the username were `Bobby` and the password were `tables`:

```
http://Bobby:tables@www.example.com/secretfolder
```

Firefox will ask for confirmation before sending the username and password.

**Be warned**: Using this method means that **anyone with access to your bookmarks will be able to log in**. Your credentials would be stored in plain text just like any other bookmark.

This is not Firefox-specific: it should work in any web browser.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox extension, **[Secure Login](http://securelogin.mozdev.org/)** allows you to do this.

Its feature list from [its website](http://securelogin.mozdev.org/) (I emphasized the features that you might want):

- Easy installation through Mozilla Firefox add-ons system.
- Works out of the box without any configuration needed.
- Login with one click or a keyboard shortcut (automatically submitting the login forms).
- **Easy and convenient selection for multiple logins (multiple users)**
- Provides direct login to any site from the bookmarks (using the "Secure Login Bookmarks").
- **Integrates with Mozilla Firefox password manager.**
- **Provides easy access to the saved passwords.**
- Prevents malicious JavaScript code to automatically steal your login data.
- Provides an option to protect your login data from all JavaScript code during login.
- Websites requiring JavaScript for the login process can be added to an exception list.
- Can prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks to steal your passwords without having to deactivate JavaScript.
- Helps to protect you from phishing.
- Shows the login URL(s) and the number of available logins in a tooltip of the toolbar button and the statusbar icon.
- Can be set to automatically search for login data and highlight form fields.
- Can be used with a toolbar button, a statusbar icon, a keyboard shortcut or via the context menu.
- Completely customizable interface (buttons, icons and menus can be enabled/disabled).
- Provides a customizable keyboard shortcut
- By default only active on login so it doesn't consume any system resources while surfing.
- Can fill out additional form fields using the Autofill Forms add-on.
- Possibility to play a sound when logins are found or when logging in.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question... It's a known issue, reported on December 2003:

- Bug [227632](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=227632) - Allow user to select among multiple saved logins in HTTP Basic and Digest Auth dialogs