# Making Firefox remember multiple user name/passwords for the same site

Tags: firefox, password-management

I have several gmail logins for different purposes (work, home, other family members, etc.).  Firefox happily remembers them all, but my problem is that it no longer even asks if want to remember the password when I log in under a new gmail account that it hasn't seen before.

At first I thought it was because I entered a user-name that started with a number.  However recently I created a new account to associate with a new blog and it didn't ask me about that one either.   Is there some kind of limit on how many unique usernames it will remember for a site (why???) or is there some configuration item I need to tweak to allow more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out why Firefox did not want to remember any more passwords.

I was reading the Mozilla help page on the [Password Manager](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords#w_make-firefox-remember-usernames-and-passwords), and read where it said "Clicking outside of the Remember Password prompt will hide it. To bring it back, just click the key icon on the left side of the location bar."  Instead of a key I see a lock in my version of firefox (15.0.1) so I clicked on that. That brought up some info about the game.  I clicked on the "More Information" button, and then "View saved passwords".  I realize I could get to this through the menus, but I noticed something accessing via this path that I didn't notice through the menus (maybe there were there and I just didn't notice them before, I don't know) - there was an entry for the web site that had a password but no user name.  After I deleted this entry I then tried to log in for the site, and then Firefox immediately prompted me as to whether or not to remember the login info.

So in summary, if you are having problems with Firefox not wanting to remember more passwords, check if there is an existing password that has no user name.  In my case, this made Firefox not want to remember any more passwords.

Answer (score 3):

The question about this feature was already asked [Firefox password manager - multiple logins for HTTP authentication](https://superuser.com/q/231641/274552) here, and I've [pointed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436275) both the source and the solution to the problem. As Firefox developer responsible for password manager **doesn't want** this to work properly, I've ceased uploading updated versions of the patch, however it is simple enough to be done by anyone (only some JavaScript is modified, no recompile required) and if anyone is interested (on Fx bugzilla please) I will put some newer version there.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the following extension:

[image: Multifox]

> [Multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) is an extension that allows Firefox to connect to websites using different user names. Simultaneously!
>
> For example, if you have multiple Gmail accounts, you can open them all at the same time. Each Firefox window, managed by Multifox, accesses an account without interfering each other
>
> Each Multifox window is flagged with a number indicating the identity profile. Logins made in windows with different numbers are isolated.
>
> Logins are preserved the same way they are in “regular” windows. Even if you close the window or quit Firefox.
>
> The identity profile of each window is preserved when Firefox restores the session.

It can also easily switch between profiles:
[image]

Just use a different profile for each Gmail account you have, and Multifox should remember it all. There should be no need for re-logging in when using multiple accounts with Multifox.

---

About Firefox not asking to remember the password for multiple accounts, I have not experienced that issue with Multifox. I also use the extension, **[Secure Login](http://securelogin.mozdev.org/)**, but am not sure if it will help. *Secure Login* makes auto-logging in with remembered password much easier, so I recommend you install that too, regardless. I'm listing some of its features that may be useful in your case:

> - Login with one click or a keyboard shortcut (automatically submitting the login forms).
> - Easy and convenient selection for multiple logins (multiple users)
> - Integrates with Mozilla Firefox password manager.
> - Provides easy access to the saved passwords.
> - Shows the login URL(s) and the number of available logins in a tooltip of the toolbar button and the statusbar icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Inbuilt Profile Manager** to manage multiple user profiles in firefox. You can have multiple Firefox profiles, each containing a separate set of user information, including saved password for each user. When you create a new profile, launching with a new profile will act as a Fresh Install of Firefox and will ask to Save Password.

To create new profile, Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `firefox.exe -p` and press enter.
*(This step is needed only first time, later you can launch simply as you do now.)*

If you want Firefox to ask you each time you start it which profile it should use then Remember to **Uncheck** the **Don't ask at startup** checkbox,

**Important:**
 Before you can start the Profile Manager, Firefox must be completely closed.

**Links:**

- [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)
- [Lifehacker: Manage multiple Firefox profiles](http://lifehacker.com/231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles)

Comment: I will try this, however I have to imagine this is almost as much work as just bringing up an external password manager program.

Comment: all this is needed only single time. Once you setup you will only have to launch it like you do now. It use it, and its really easy.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to this could be to use a third-party password manager, like [KeePass2](http://keepass.info/). I use KeePass2 with Chrome and a plugin that allows it to auto-fill my passwords. On sites where I have more than one password, like Gmail, I am offered a choice of numerous accounts to use. There is a similar plugin for Firefox and KeePass called [PassIFox](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#passifox).

Comment: I already have my own password storage solution, in which I store my passwords in an encrypted database locally.  However, for non-security critical things like e-mail it's still somewhat of a pain to have to bring it up, find the required password, and copy/paste.  I guess I could consider just writing a Firefox extension that talks to my database, eh?

Comment: Well, you could...but you might be able to just adapt PassIFox, actually. For what it's worth, KeePass2 is also a locally-stored database - I too am wary of putting my passwords in the cloud. Mine is secured using a keyfile and a passphrase (two factors), and I sync it using Google Drive so I have it at all my computers. Another note - your email password is arguably one of the more important ones, since if it is compromised, an attacker can then use password resets to compromise other, more sensitive passwords (like banking).

Comment: If you sync it using Google Drive then I guess it's in the cloud, one way or another.  I'm not confident enough to do that, yet.

Comment: It is, but I have faith in the encryption on it (since it's controlled by me and not Google). Still, it took me awhile to get to that point (I used to carry it around on an IronKey, which effectively meant double-encryption).